# How to get content height of ScrollView component for contentOffset prop in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

For my current project, I'm creating a Diary/Calendar type component that shows the current day (Diary view) or current month (Calendar view) centered when the user clicks to see that view.

I'm using a ScrollView to hold my content:

```
_getInitialOffset(h) {
  const FIX = 75; //TODO: Make it less arbitrary
  let percentToScroll = (this.props.viewedDate.month()+1)/12; //12 = number of months per year
  let { height } = this.props;
  let centerFix = height/2;
  let contentHeight = h;
  let yPos = contentHeight*percentToScroll - centerFix - FIX;
  return (yPos > 0) ? yPos : 0;
}



render() {
  var year = this.props.viewedDate.year();
  var cal = Calendar.get(year);
  var contentHeight = this.contentHeight;
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.daysOfWeek}>
        {
          Calendar.days().map(function(day, i) {
            return <Text key={i} style={styles.dayHeader}>{day}</Text>;
          })
        }
      </View>
      <ScrollView
        ref={ref => {this._scrollView = ref}}
        style={{
          height: this.props.height,
          paddingTop: 15
        }}
        onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => {
          this._scrollView.scrollTo({y: this._getInitialOffset(h), animated: false});
        }}>
        <Year year={year} calendar={cal}/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to have it center upon render on the current month, but because my current method (using OnContentSizeChange) occurs after render, there's a frame where the user sees it uncentered, which is bad user experience.

**Is there a way to get the content height of a ScrollView component before/during render, or delay component visibility until after the onContentSizeChange method has fired?**

Comment: Are you using constrains?

Comment: Constraints in React Native?

Answer (score 4):

`onContentSizeChange` is internally using [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) which is triggered as soon as the layout has been computed.

> This event is fired immediately once the layout has been calculated, but the new layout may not yet be reflected on the screen at the time the event is received, especially if a layout animation is in progress.

There's no way to get the size before that.
So what you can do is set the `opacity` of your scrollview to 0 until the first `onContentSizeChange` is triggered.

I advise you to use `Animated.Value` to do the opacity change so it doesn't re-render your whole component.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is as follows:

1. Create a parent container, with scrollOffset animation that tracks the amount of scroll.
2. Get the height of the ScrollView container ("containerHeight")
3. Get the height of the contents within the ScrollView ("contentHeight")
4. Use the ScrollView's "onScroll" event to get the scroll offset. Use it to update the scrollOffset animation.
5. Create a ScrollBar component based on the scrollOffset animation value, containerHeight, and contentHeight

The following is extracted from my code. It is incomplete and untested, but should be enough to for one to get started.

```js
class CustomScrollView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollOffsetAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  renderScrollBar() {
    const {
      scrollOffsetAnim,
      contentHeight,
      containerHeight,
    } = this.state;

    //...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <ScrollView
              scrollEventThrottle={16}
              onScroll={(evt) => {
                  const {contentOffset} = evt.nativeEvent;
                  const {y} = contentOffset;
                  this.state.scrollOffsetAnim.setValue(y);
              }}
              onLayout={(evt) => {
                  const {height} = evt.nativeEvent.layout;
                  const {containerHeight} = this.state;
                  if(!containerHeight || containerHeight !== height) {
                      this.setState({containerHeight: height})
                  }
              }}
          >
              <View 
                  onLayout={(evt) => {
                      const {height} = evt.nativeEvent.layout;
                      const {contentHeight} = this.state;
                      if(!contentHeight || contentHeight !== height) {
                          this.setState({contentHeight: height})
                      }
                  }}
              >
                  {this.props.children}
              </View>
          </ScrollView>
          {this.renderScrollBar()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get the total height of the insides of a scrollview, just add a **generic View** with the **onLayout** prop inside it:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}} >
  <View style ={{flex:1}} onLayout={e=>console.log('e',e.nativeEvent.layout)}>
    {YOUR VIEWS HERE}
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Every time the component rerenders, it will print the console log **('e')** with the informations you probably wishes